# _winreg.QueryValueEx returns "mixed typed" binary value

Tags: python, python-3.x, registry, winreg

Under Python 3.4, I'm using `winreg.QueryValueEx()` to get key values from the registry in order to compare it to text files.
I've encountered a problem where the `REG_BINARY` key value is `bytes` but in it there are unicode values:

- Expected Registry key value - 52 50 43 46 01 1b 00 00 00 ff fe ff 04 46 00 6c 00 61...
- Returned key value - b'**RPCF**\x01\x1b\x00\x00\x00\xff\xfe\xff **\x04F\x00l\x00a\x00t\x00\x00\n**\x00\x8b...' (bolded some problematic values)
- tried some decode\encode options, all failed due to the mixed type (e.g. `key_val.decode('utf-8')` returned `{UnicodeDecodeError}'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 9: invalid start byte`)

I use the returned value, which is a list of hex values, to a text file holding expected hex values. These bolded values are not expected since they are not in hex format and I don't know them all in advance to do some workarounds to handle them specifically.

In Python 2.7, there wasn't any problem. I'm guessing this has to do with Python 3 separating `str` and `bytes` or even a bug in winreg in Python 3.

Would appreciate any assistance and tip in order to unify it to a single type.
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you consider the bolded values to be problematic?  What are you trying to do with the return value that is failing? You can learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I expected those values to be \x52\x50\x43\x46 instead of RPCF for example - All the bytes in same format.
added info for my usage of returned value.

Comment: Those values are in fact the same.  You are simply seeing an artifact of how python displays strings versus bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your data in the registry is not even unicode.
Do you even need to decode it to unicode?

Why not store the data in a binary file?

```
bytes_data = winreg.QueryValueEx(your_key)
with open("filename.txt", "wb") as stream:
    stream.write(bytes_data)
```

Comment: Thanks Nir! I just compared the read byte array to the one read from the reference and no decode\encode was needed! :)